# Undeclared and undefined identifier's in the parameter of a function

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;
  void instructions();
int menu();
void drawt(int& s, char& c);



int main()
{

int choice;
instructions();
choice = menu();
if (choice != 1 && choice != 2)
{
    cout << "You requested to quit. Bye! \n";
    return 0;
} 
if (choice = 1) {

    drawt(s, c);
}
//draw the shape the user requested
//draw_shape(choice);
system("pause");
return 0;
}
void instructions() {
cout << "This program will create a triangle or diamond of your choice in 
size!\n";
cout << "The number you enter will either be the size of the bottom of the 
triangle or the size of the middle of the diamond!\n";
}
int menu() {
int c;
cout << "Please choose between drawing a triangle, diamond or exiting the 
program!\n";
cout << "Enter 1 for a triangle,2 for a diamond and 3 to exit!\n";
cin >> c;
   return c;
   }

   void drawt(int& s, char& c){
  cout << "enter base size of triangle\n";
  cin >> s;
   cout << "Now enter the character you wish the triangle to be made of!\n";
   cin >> c;
   int length = 1;

    for (int i= 0; i < 5; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < s; j++) {
        cout << c;
    }

    cout << endl;
    length++;
    if (length = s) {
        break;
        }
      }
   }
```

it says that both S and C are undefined and undeclared, and i have no clue why it wont work.I just learned functions and i am not sure whether i am calling it correctly or used the header correctly or what exactly i have done wrong.I have looked up so many tutorials and such. The program is suppose to draw a triangle, or diamond whichever the person picks and then draw it out of the character of their choice. it isn't close to done but im so hung up on this right now. thank you!

Comment: You must declare ```s``` and ```c``` in main() in order to use them there. I.e. you need a ```int s;``` and ```char c;``` somewhere before you do ```drawt(s,c);```.

Comment: @nick He does need to declare them but he doesn't need to initialize them in main(). They aren't const and are assigned in the drawt function. But it is good practice to initialize variables.

Comment: @doug you are right, I wasn't looking at what he was doing with them in ```drawt()```.

Comment: Could you, please, format the code better? It's terribly indented and hard to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call this function from `main()`:

```
drawt(s, c);
```

You are sending 2 variables, s and c, to the function. But these variables don't exist yet in `main()` -- that is the compilation problem here. You need to first declare them in `main()`:

```
int s;
char c;
```

That should solve your basic problem.

You should try to practice with functions a bit more. You have some problems (not critical) with the way you have defined `drawt()` -- it is using arguments that could actually be defined locally, and it is receiving them as references even though `main()` never uses them. These are important things that you should learn about, but they won't break your program as it is right now.

Also, you should immediately start indenting consistently -- it's pretty important :)